# Multi-Master Replication for PostgreSQL in two geographically distant locations

Tags: postgresql, master-master-replication

I have an Odoo 13 instance running with a PostgreSQL 12 database on the same instance in one location. I want to create another instance in another location with the same codebase and database. I want these two databases to sync / replicate changes to one another to improve High Availability and Latency for users in both location.

So far I've tried the following but none of them worked as expected:

1. [Odoo module for Multi-DB Synchronization (base_synchro)](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/base_synchro/), It keeps duplicating the records, does not support DDL operation like module install/ remove and only synch selected tables (models)
2. Multi-Master Replication using Bucardo, doesn't discover DDL alterations or replicate it, it needs to done manually
3. Compiled PostgreSQL BDR 9.4 ( But Odoo minimum PostgreSQL version is 9.6), I couldn't found one for PostgreSQL 9.6 or later.

I want to know an efficient way for scaling a typical monolithic web application like Odoo.